# Motherboard pins look a bit off - are they broken?

Tags: motherboard, sockets, processor-socket

I'm new to PCs and don't know much. I know that motherboard pins are easy to bend and I don't know if these pins are bent or not. They seem to point in the right direction but look odd.
If I start the PC the way the socket is right now, what would happen?

The motherboard uses a LGA1700 socket.

Close up:

[image: Close up]

Comment: The picture is not very clear, but it should be fine as long as those two contact springs are not disconnected/loose, not touching other contacts, and not reaching into a neighboring "cell"

Answer (score 0):

As @Cpt.Whale alludes to in the comments, they appear to be in usable condition, provided they are not touching neighbouring pins and make contact with your CPU contacts.

If you have a very steady hand, a good magnifying glass, lots of light and a pin or very fine tweezers, you can try gently nudging them back into position, but it is a risk any which way you look at it. If you break the pin, you are goosed.

I encountered the same problem just a few weeks ago - in fact two pins were damaged and one was bent backwards. It was only after trying multiple CPUs and not getting anything coming up on the display that I spotted the slight shadows in the CPU socket and realised the problem. I was successful in adjusting the pins back into position, which I count myself very lucky for!

Given that the system was otherwise undamaged by me trying to power it on with the damaged pins, I would guess your safest bet is to try it as is, and if it fails to boot, only then try adjusting the pins.